# CSS Background Image css/html

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver, mozilla

I am working on a site for a friend, and am having trouble with our first draft. Basically i am trying to just get a background image that fits well. When i test the code in Dreamweaver it works how i want it to, but however when i test it on the live site the background image doesnt appear in Firefox, though it does when i test from my own computer, any help? Also the site seems to work fine in IE.

live site: **www.crookednosebeer.com**

css:

(I think the problem occurs in the css, when i am trying to root the img)

```
body{
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
background-color: #b2b2b2;
background: url(../images/trial2.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Does your image exist on your webserver?

Comment: Your CSS is not being parsed at all: `<link href="file:///C|/wamp/www/crookednose/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`. Use a real URL (just `/css/style.css` should work).

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As @bfavaretto commented, you set a local system path for the CSS file that you want to use in your HTML file. You'll have to replace it with a URI relative to your WWW root so remote clients can also read it. Change your HEAD section into this:

```
<head>
<title>Crooked Nose</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
</head>
```

(tested in Chrome)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try quoting the url

```
background: url("../images/trial2.gif") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

the url for css in the "link rel" area..try to use link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"..ahm try in chrome..

happy coding...